# DhcpInfo isn't responding the netmask in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, netmask

Yesterday I update my nexus 5 to lollipop and my application stops working, after a little investigation I found the problem the DhcpInfo isn't is returning null on the netmask variable.

I couldn't find any alternative to this class.

Comment: I have the same problem and didn't find a solution yet. However where did you read that DhcpInfo is deprecated?

Comment: Seems that the DhcpInfo isn't deprecated anymore, but my app is configured to API 18, in API 18 it use to be deprecated  :) http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/19/changes/android.net.wifi.WifiManager.html

Comment: You use Android Lollipop. So you should use Android API level 21 :)

Comment: It seems a bug of Lollipop. I just buy a HTC nexus 9 with Android 5.0, and my App doesn't work on it. After checking the code, DhcpInfo's netmask always return 0.

Comment: It's this bug in Android 5: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82477

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getNetworkPrefixLength` method of `InterfaceAddress`, which you get from `NetworkInterface`. It returns the correct value  in Lollipop.

```
NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ipAddress);
for (InterfaceAddress address : networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
    short netPrefix = address.getNetworkPrefixLength());
}
```

Note: It returns network prefix length, so you'd have to convert it (/24 for 255.255.255.0 etc.)

Comment: will this return the wifi prefix or the WAN prefix?